# What are some preferred practices to handle systematics uncertainties for fitted model parameters?

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling, parameter-estimation, data-analysis

I have a set of data $(x_{\rm data}, y_{\rm data}, \Delta y_{{\rm data}})$, where $\Delta y_{{\rm data}}$ is the uncertainty in the measurement. I also have some model used to explain the data. The model is non-linear:$$y_{\rm model} =\mathcal{F}(\bf{p}; x_{\rm model})~,$$
$\bf{p}$ being the model parameters. I have some prior knowledge about $\bf{p}$, so I run MCMC chain to estimate the posterior distribution of $\bf{p}$, and use that distribution to find the best-fit values and the uncertainties for $\bf{p}$. This is all good. However, I have few (less than 10) candidate models to explain the dataset, and the true model is unknown. All these models give different estimate for best-fit values and the uncertainties of $\bf{p}$. Thus, I need some good method which could be used to calculate the best-fit values and the uncertainties of $\bf{p}$, such that the model uncertainty is also included. While calculating such systematic uncertainty I also need to keep in mind that some of these models fit the data poorly compared to others (measured with some metric like $\chi^2 =\sum (y_{\rm data}- y_{\rm model})^2/\Delta y_{\rm data}^2$). Any suggestions?

P.S. For model selection, I came across information criterion like the Akaike Information Criterion, so my naive thought was choose the best model from such criterion and report the best-fit value and uncertainty of the parameters for such best-fit model.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You say that you need some way of calculating the best-fit values and uncertainties, but right before you also say that all of the models give different estimates for these values. So if you know that they give different estimates, then it seems like you already have a way to compute them! From your PS it sounds like you want to do some sort of model comparison, so you might want to look into Bayes Factor and BIC in addition to AIC, perhaps one of these will give you what you want.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the question "Thus, I need some good method which could be used to calculate the best-fit values and the uncertainties of , such that the model uncertainty is also included." Besides uncertainty in data, there is also uncertainty in the model, and I want these uncertainties to be accounted for while reporting the best fit model parameters.

Comment: Well you have already mentioned AIC, and I also mentioned BIC and Marginal Likelihood. These are all standard metrics for the kind of thing you want to do. If this is not satisfactory to you, then please clarify why your notion of "model uncertainy" is different than what is captured by these metrics.

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty in the estimated parameters $\mathbf{p}$ can be measured by their (estimated) standard error and confidence intervals. While comparison between different models (on the same data) is indeed can be conducted using the AIC or the BIC criteria. You can give the standard error or the confidence intervals of the difference in the AIC criteria between different models, which gives you some metric of the significance of your improvement (or the final model). If you compare between models in the same family, e.g., linear models, then you have well established algorithms for models selection (F test or AIC using Backward\forward\stepwise variables selection). If you compare between different types of models (e.g., linear with fixed effects and non linear with mixed effects, then AIC \ BIC with uncertainty metrics like standard errors is probably the most suitable choice).